# R Leaflet change layer order

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to produce a leaflet map in R with a layer (e.g. WMS tile or raster) and some circles. Since there are many circles in my application, I need to change the order, i.e. the layer should be shown on top of the circles.

Is there a way in R to change the order such that I can bring the WMS tile to the front or sent the circles to the background?

My code looks like the following (in a simplified way):

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 4) %>% 
addCircles(lng=-98,lat=40,radius=100000,color = "red",stroke=FALSE,fillOpacity=1) %>% 
  addWMSTiles(
    baseUrl="http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r.cgi",
    layers ="nexrad-n0r-900913",
    options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
    attribution = "Weather data © 2012 IEM Nexrad"
    )
```

Comment: I assume this is in an interactive setting? If so, how about just [show/hide layers](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html)??

Comment: No, in this case it won't be. The goal is to save it as an html widget without any interaction.